# UserDefaults in IOS 10 is sometimes showing old value

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am testing something on my app where I save the current used theme as a string: "Light" vs "Dark".

I just realized that at some point when I keep switching from light to dark (reading and writing the string to `UserDefaults`) I sometimes get on old value:

```
Light -> Dark -> Light -> Dark -> Light -> Light
```

I have added logs to where I read and write the value and its doing it correctly. This is how I test:

```
 1. Start app 
 2. Change theme (save string to UserDefaults)
 3. Stop app
 4. Start app (read string from UserDefaults)
```

I saw some other posts which says there is a problem with `UserDefaults` in `IOS 10` and the solution is to restart device or mac.

I get this, but doesn't this mean the issue will appear on the user device as well ? 
Has anyone encounter this kind of issue ? Any solution ?

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 with IOS 10, Swift 3. And I am testing on my real device, not simulator.

Comment: Are you sure the value does write itself into userdefalts? I mean, you can try the syncronize thing. They doesn't recommend it however for me it seems like it don't write the value so fast into disk.

Comment: Can you please show us a code?

Comment: I did some more testing and I just realized that this issue occurs when I restart quickly, right after the item is saving. If I pause for two seconds, it seems I don't have the issue.

Comment: Then my solution is for you. Use syncronize to immediately save the value.

Comment: '.synchronise()' returns a bool which indicates whether it was saved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after saving Data?